# select single row based on value in column not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a temp table

```
create table temp 
(
Id int ,
A int , 
B int )
```

which for sample contains

```
insert into temp(Id,A,B)values(456,1,null)
insert into temp(Id,A,B)values(456,null,2)
```

two rows

Now i want my result set to be a single row as Id for both rows same and A should contains not null value in this case is 1 and B should also contain not null value which is in above case is 2.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do this, but what if the values in both rows are not `null`?  Which should it use?  Or should it return both results?

Comment: at least there always one row contains null value and for a Id there always will be two rows only.

Answer (score 3):

Given your comments, this might be the easiest option using `max` with `group by`:

```
select id, max(a), max(b)
from temp
group by id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cf9a7/1)

However, if there are non-null values for multiple rows, this might not produce your desired results.

Comment: what in case there will be value not integer but text value

Comment: @rahularyansharma -- that would be impossible with your example table schema, but it should work the same way with any data type.  Here's another example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c6a72/1

Comment: yes schema is sample one.

Comment: now in case using this result set i have to update another table , which if contains Id value then update else insert .

Comment: @rahularyansharma -- Honestly given your reputation, I would hope you wouldn't ask one question and then lead to another question and another.  This appropriately answers your original post.  Please post a new question vs asking additional ones in the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `merge` statement to do either update or insert based on your id:

```
MERGE Temp1 AS t1
USING (
    SELECT id
        ,max(a) as [A]
        ,max(b) as [B]
    FROM TEMP
    GROUP BY id
    ) AS t
    ON (T.id = T1.id)
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN
        UPDATE
        SET t1.[A] = t.[A],
            t1.[B] = t.[B]
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN
        INSERT (Id,A,B)
        VALUES (
            t.[id],t.[A],t.[B]);
```